# Plotting “large” image with points with matplotlib - MemoryError

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot an image of 3193 x 3293 pixels with 1502 points. When running in a smaller image and less points (934,722 pixels and 60 points), everything runs perfectly.

I wrote like this:

```
# I am just giving the general characteristics of the data;    
img = numpy.ndarray, dtype = uint8, shape = (3193,3293) 
points = numpy.ndarray, dtype = int32, shape = (1502,2)

plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray_r)
plt.autoscale(False)
plt.plot(points[:, 1], points[:, 0], 'r.', markersize = 15)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Is there any other way to do this without using that much memory?

Answer (score 1):

`matplotlib.imshow()` can only plot grayscales [if they are of dtype float](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow). Your memory error is most likely due to an internal copy, which changes your dtype from `uint8` to `float32/64`.

Do you have enough memory to drectly work with `img = numpy.ndarray, dtype = float32`? If not your best bet is most likely to write the image directly to disc, using for instance [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), which should be able to take `dtype = uint8` arrays as input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kersten.
That is exactly what is happening. I am having a problem with a internal copy. Currently I have 16GB of memory. The problem is that I have to work with float data. Each pixel corresponds to a height value. If I use uint8 I will have problems with precision.

Comment: If you are working with floats no copy should happen, but you specified `img = numpy.ndarray, dtype = uint8, shape = (3193,3293)`. I am confused, which dtype is your dataset?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. First a tried using uint8 but then I realized I could not use it because of the precision. Then I tried using float format. But I still have a MemoryError.