# Plotting tiff file giving Memory Error

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to plot GIS data, a tiff file using gdal and then imshow() function but I am getting the following error -

[image]

My code is -

```
import gdal
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as ml


try:
    tif = gdal.Open('lulc250k_1415_13861.tif')
    tifArray = tif.ReadAsArray()
except:
    print 'The file does not exist.'
    sys.exit(0)

band1 = tif.GetRasterBand(1)

band1Array = band1.ReadAsArray()

pyplot.imshow(band1Array)
pyplot.show()
```

The gdalinfo of the file -

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: lulc250k_1415_13861.tif
Size is 32716, 22789
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (72.486328125000000,32.233886718750000)
Pixel Size = (0.000509086484824,-0.000509086072228)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  72.4863281,  32.2338867) ( 72d29'10.78"E, 32d14' 1.99"N)
Lower Left  (  72.4863281,  20.6323242) ( 72d29'10.78"E, 20d37'56.37"N)
Upper Right (  89.1416016,  32.2338867) ( 89d 8'29.77"E, 32d14' 1.99"N)
Lower Right (  89.1416016,  20.6323242) ( 89d 8'29.77"E, 20d37'56.37"N)
Center      (  80.8139648,  26.4331055) ( 80d48'50.27"E, 26d25'59.18"N)
Band 1 Block=32716x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  NoData Value=0
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
```

Comment: please add gdalinfo output on lulc250k_1415_13861.tif

Comment: @IanTurton
I've updated the question with gdalinfo!

Comment: Do you need to plot this in Python? If not, just drag it into QGIS. If it's still slow to load, you can build overviews on it.

Comment: And the tool for building overviews is gdaladdo http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html.

Comment: @Jon I do need to plot this in python.

Comment: You may be out of luck, then. If it's just for automating figure creation, your other option would be to coarsen the resolution. You can use skimage.transform.resize or scipy.ndimage.zoom for easy resolution manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

A MemoryError like this usually means that something ran out of memory (i.e. it's too big for your system to process as is). Your image dimensions (number of pixels) and data type for each pixel (uint8, float32, etc.) will influence how much memory is used. This type of error can also be related to figures hanging around in memory.

See this tutorial for info on clearing out old figures from memory: https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/

Some similar questions also suggest using the PIL library as one solution:

- [Plotting “large” image with points with matplotlib - MemoryError](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155042/plotting-large-image-with-points-with-matplotlib-memoryerror)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525706/excessive-memory-usage-in-matplotlib-imshow